# Notepad++ - Replace text not matching regex pattern

Tags: regex, notepad++

All other questions I find relating to this question only focus on finding specific characters using squared brackets (`[]`) and inverting it with `^`, but this does not work for me because I want to invert an expression that does not include specifying exact characters.

My regex expression is: `^(5\d+)`

This finds all lines in a document that start with 5 and only contain other digits.

So, for example, it will find lines which only contain ID numbers, such as 5030202, but it will ignore anything else. This is great except I want to replace every line in the file that does NOT match this expression with nothing so that I am only left with only these values (remove everything else except these ID numbers).

**How can I invert this expression to select everything else instead?**

Thanks.

Comment: I guess, it was already answered in SuperUser:
https://superuser.com/questions/290247/delete-all-lines-in-notepad-except-lines-containing-a-word-i-need and SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051097/notepad-deleting-all-text-except-what-matches-regex

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep whole lines of digits that start with `5`? Try `^(?!5\d+$).*\R?`

Comment: Thank you. It was the `.*\R?` part that I was missing. I already looked at the question posted as "already answered" and tried using `?!` but that on its own did not work.

Comment: I found the explanation lacking; "carriage return optional" was required to get this to work for some reason. Very confusing. EDIT: Actually it was `.*` that was required!